# CSS Menu Hover Underline Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an underline animation when hovering on menu items (based on this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mehi/pen/MyWqPM)). For some reason, all my menu items are underlined instead of just one when hovering. I only want the menu item that is hovered to be underlined, not everything.

Here is my code:

```css
html {
  background-color: #131313;
}

.pages {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  list-style: none;
}

.pages li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.pages a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pages a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width .4s ease;
}

.pages a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pages">
  <li><a href="#top" id="menu-home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" id="menu-about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#work" id="menu-work">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="#projects" id="menu-proj">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#connect" id="menu-connect">Connect</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please help!

Comment: remove `position:absolute` from `.pages a:after `

Comment: thank you!! that worked! can you explain why that made a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position:absolute` from `.pages a:after`. Elements with [absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) positioning are not in the normal document flow. In your snippet your 100% width will not be 100% of `a` but 100% of nearest relativly/absolutly positioned parent(body by defaul; ul in your case).

As an alternative, you may set `position:relative` to li, so that `:after` element will be underlying li.

```css
html {
  background-color: #131313;
}

.pages {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  list-style: none;
}

.pages li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative
}

.pages a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pages a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width .4s ease;
}

.pages a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pages">
  <li><a href="#top" id="menu-home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" id="menu-about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#work" id="menu-work">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="#projects" id="menu-proj">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#connect" id="menu-connect">Connect</a></li>
</ul>
```

My explanation may be to complicated so you may look at snippet below. I tried to explain positioning.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#parent {
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#child1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#child2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class='box'>
  <!--parent-->

  <!-- relative element stays relative to it's original position but can be shifted-->
  <div id="child1" class='box'>position:relative with "top"and"left" of 10px</div>

  <div id="child2" class='box'>position:absolute</div>
</div>
<!--
notice how yellow box is stays where it should be without "top"&"left" assigned, but it's owerlaping shifted green box
-->
```